# Recursion in Metal ios

Tags: ios, recursion, metal

Does Metal shading language support recursion?
I have code :

```
 Intersection traceScene(Ray ray, int step) {
    Intersection retIntersection = Intersection();
    Intersection i1 = trianglePrism.intersect(ray);
    Intersection i2 = image.intersect(ray);
    if (i1.intersect) {
        Ray newRay = Ray(i1.position, Refract(ray.direction, trianglePrism.normal, 0.71));
        return traceScene(newRay, step + 1);
    } else {
        if (i2.intersect) {
            return i2;
        } else {
            return Intersection();
        }
    }
    return retIntersection;
}
```

But when i build kernel function which use it, it occur error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Metal shading language is based on C++ 11 but with some specific extensions and restrictions. One of the restrictions is that recursive function calls are not allowed so the short answer is no, you can't do this.

I won't paste in the complete list of differences since I don't know how likely to change it is but they are covered in the section 'Metal and C++ 11' in Apple's Metal Shading Language Guide.

Comment: Recursive functions can be implemented [using macros in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77470186/975097), so this may be possible in Metal as well.